# Работа со словарём в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.
Речь идёт о Python Django.
В файле views.py в функции я передаю в шаблон словарь:

```
array = {'Bob': 10, 'Alex': 12}
```

В шаблоне в цикле я вывожу так эти данные:

```
{% for i in array %}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Но так я получаю только ключ: а мне надо так же получать и значение.
Как мне это можно сделать? Ведь в шаблоне возможности цикла сильно ограничены, и я не могу написать так:

```
{% for i in array.items() %}
...
```

Будет ошибка.
Что делать?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Просто items без скобок:

```
{% for key, value in array.items %}
  {{ key }} = {{ value }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

А ещё могу посоветовать перейти на шаблонатор Jinja2, там почти ничего не ограничено и почти полноценный питон в шаблонах.

Comment: Всё равно, тоже самое. (ошибка)

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: Сверху написано: 'int' object is not iterable. 
И ниже html код шаблона приведён с выделенной строкой: {% for key, value in test.items %}

Comment: Неаккуратный копипаст моего кода, что ли? Заменить test на array?

Comment: Нет, в своём коде я всё правильно сделал. Просто тут названия для переменных поменял, чтобы было понятно Вам.

Comment: То есть, в своём коде вы передали тот самый `array` из вопроса, и django для `array.items` выдаёт  `'int' object is not iterable`? Можете привести код, в котором данные передаются в шаблон?

Comment: @andreymal, Jinja2 по возможностям не сильно отличается от шаблонизатора Django, а полноценный Python в шаблонах — это скорее зло, чем добро, так как нарушается разделение кода и представления. Впрочем, это лишь моё мнение.

Comment: @velikodniy он там не полностью полноценный: никаких импортов не сделаешь (хотя если очень захотеть, то можно, но это уже ССЗБ), с пространствами имён не поиграешься, ещё на какие-то ограничения натыкался. Но при этом он значительно упрощает задачи подобные этой, благодаря чему не придётся дописывать какой-нибудь хлам в коде с обходом недостатков джанги и можно будет оставить всё представление именно в представлении :)

Comment: Для меня это сработало, с `{{ key }} = {{ value }}`, но у меня был словарь в словаре, и я использовала `{{value.НазваниеМоегоКлюча}}` для доступа.